How to retrieve the Web Browser's language configuration in TMS WEB Core?
I'm working on a TMS WEB Core app where I need to display values to the user in their preferred language. Currently, I'm using the FormatSettings to handle formatting, but I'm struggling with getting the correct language configuration.
I know how to change some values of the current FormatSettings and how it works with respect to the Web Browser.
In my app, I use FormatSettings to introduce data and display the user-selected configuration.
When communicating with the backend, I force a concrete format momentarily, which works well.
However, sometimes the backend returns values that must be shown to the user in their browser's language.
Question Details:
How can I retrieve the Web Browser's language configuration (e.g., "en-US", "en-UK", "es-US", "es-ES", etc.) and store it in a variable within my TMS WEB Core app?
Are there any specific APIs or methods I should use to achieve this?

You can get it using either one of these two methods as they both return the same values.


GetBrowserLocale function from the WEBLib.Tools unit:

uses
  WEBLib.WebTools;

...

procedure TForm1.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(GetBrowserLocale);
end;


window.navigator.language function from the Web unit:

uses
  Web;

...

procedure TForm1.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(window.navigator.language);
end;

